# Is it possible to default to quiet references in NVelocity?

Tags: c#, .net, templates, nvelocity

I'm using NVelocity to build an email message. Rather than mark every reference as quiet ($!name instead of $name), I'd like to default to quiet references.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you would be able to set this is in NVelocity would be through setting some standard property. Looking at the [supported Velocity RuntimeConstants for properties](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.2/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/RuntimeConstants.html), there isn't any such property, so I guess it's not possible.